# Facebook ignores og:title, use heading instead

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're trying to share comments from our site so we created special pages with special og tags. Facebook scrape all information on these pages corretly (including og:title), but when you share this page, Facebook use h4 instead of `og:title`. [Link](http://zpravy.idnes.cz/diskuse.aspx?iddiskuse=A150713_165209_domaci_pku&vlakno=73228884&idreakce=73228884#73228884)

Comment: Can you check the encoding of your page? Is windows-1250 indeed correct? Can you encode the value of the og:title meta tag?

Comment: Windows-1250 is correct, we have all the web in this encoding. It is very costly to change it to utf-8 with no effect for viewers. How do you mean "encode value"? Because on the rest of the web og:title works fine.

Comment: I can see Facebook is now displaying correctly the og:title. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, now it's ok. Problem was with page anchor - Facebook took heading instead of og:title because page had an anchor #.